# I want to look up a unique number in a table and get row and column name

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a two table in Excel. I want to search for the code in column B in the first table. I want to write row and column names in column C when I find this value in the array in the second table.

[Excel screenshot - More details are included in the screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JudEJ.png)

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xtlKa.png]

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to [so]! We expect questions here to relate to _specific_ programming problems. Just telling what you want is likely to be considered as "too broad" or "unclear what you are asking". We expect everyone to do some own research first. Tell us what you've tried, and where you are stuck. See also: [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In cell C2 and copied down:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($F$2:$I$3,B2)=0,"",INDEX($1:$1,,SUMPRODUCT(($F$2:$I$3=B2)*COLUMN($F$2:$I$3)))&"-"&INDEX($E:$E,SUMPRODUCT(($F$2:$I$3=B2)*ROW($F$2:$I$3))))
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend splitting Column C into two columns. For the formula that I wrote, I put Room in Column C and Table in Column D.

This formula goes into cell B2:

```
“=index($F$2:$I$3,match($D2,$E$2:$E$3,0),match($C2,$F$1:$I$1,0))”
```